# A haskell "withSubprocess" construct around a do block

Tags: selenium, haskell

I'm working through the Haskell WebDriver selenium package for testing, [here](https://github.com/kallisti-dev/hs-webdriver/blob/master/examples/readme-example-beginner.md).

I have this example:

```
import Test.WebDriver

firefoxConfig :: WDConfig
firefoxConfig = defaultConfig

main :: IO ()
main = runSession firefoxConfig $ do                      
  openPage "http://google.com"                            
  searchInput <- findElem ( ByCSS "input[type='text']" )  
  sendKeys "Hello, World!" searchInput                    
  submit searchInput                                      
  closeSession
```

The [getting started section](https://github.com/kallisti-dev/hs-webdriver#getting-started) makes clear that the selenium client requires a selenium server to communicate with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-*.jar
```

Without it running, you get this:

```
ghci    λ> main
*** Exception: FailedConnectionException2 "127.0.0.1" 4444 False connect: does not exist (Connection refused)
```

I'd like to wrap my whole test script in a function that initializes the selenium-server, records its pid, and kill(pid) after I run the session.  That is, for the duration of my existing main, I'd like to call the java selenium-server into existence, but I'd like it to stop existing as soon as the call finishes.

In python I'd do this by something like defining a `__enter__()` and an `__exit__()` with other tear-down stuff, `subprocess.Popen`, record the id, kill it, then calling

```
with Browser() as b:
  do_stuff
```

I get the sense the runSession entity is the kind of thing I would need to replicate to wrap startup and teardown like this in the sense that it takes the `firefoxConfig $ do` block as an argument and I want to do that, too.

However, I can't quite understand the types from interrogating runSession, how to make this kind of thing:

```
ghci    λ> :t runSession
runSession
  :: Test.WebDriver.Config.WebDriverConfig conf =>
     conf -> WD a -> IO a
```

I think I'd be looking for some kind of withMonad I could apply to this which is applied to the `do`. I think the syntax would be some kind of...

```
import Test.WebDriver
import System.Process

firefoxConfig :: WDConfig
firefoxConfig = defaultConfig

withBrowser :: Monad a -> Monad a -- maybe this type?
withBrowser = do
  r <- createProcess (proc "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-*.jar" [])
  -- other magic here?

main :: IO ()
main = withBrowser $ runSession firefoxConfig $ do                      
  openPage "http://google.com"                            
  searchInput <- findElem ( ByCSS "input[type='text']" )  
  sendKeys "Hello, World!" searchInput                    
  submit searchInput                                      
  closeSession
```

How would I achieve this?  Is monad right at all?  Is there a more Haskell idiom or strategy for this?

Comment: A `Monad` isn't a type. Also, keep it simple. `createProcess' and `runSession` both use `IO`, so stay in `IO`. `withBrowser :: IO a -> IO a`.

Comment: Why not use a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just want `bracket` from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket .

It allows you to specify setup and teardown IO actions to to run around a third action. It automatically handles feeding the output of the setup action into both the main and teardown actions, do your setup action should just give the PID as it's result, so the teardown action will be told what PID to kill.

Something like:

```
withBrowser browserAction
  = bracket startSelenium killSelenium (const browserAction)
```

(Where I've assumed you don't want the main action to have to take an argument for the pid, so I used `const` to ignore it)

Comment: Is that bracket_ to avoid the arg?

Comment: @Mittenchops Initially I thought that's what you'd want too, but note that the cleanup action doesn't have an argument there either. So you wouldn't have  a way to transport the PID from the startup action to the cleanup one (without sticking it in an IORef or something).